# How can we determine the appropriate number of hidden layers, kernels in convolutional neural network (CNN)?

Tags: conv-neural-network, hyperparameter, filter

I have checked a lot of questions here and in other websites. What I concluded is that there is no rules for choosing the right number of hyper-parameters in CNN, all what can we do is just trying many cases, and select the best one. Thus, I still wondering if we can choose a preliminary number  of those hyper-parameters (*point to start*) based on the type of input images (*histological medical images in my case*), the size and the number of input data, the architecture of the network, etc.

Glad to get a more additional explanation / helpful links. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some good rules of thumb for selecting hyperparameters are:

Number of layers: between 5 and 100, depending on how difficult the task is. You can start with 5 and work your way up. If you want more than 10 layers, probably use skip/residual connections of some form.

Number of kernels: start with a small number (16, 32, or 64) on your first layer, and double the number every time your feature map shrinks by 2 on each side (due to either a pooling layer or a strided conv).

Kernel size: 3x3 everywhere except the first layer, where you can use something slightly larger.

Comment: Can I use a portion of input data to find the best values of these hyper-parameters in order to speed up the process, or I have to test them with all the available data?

Comment: not really, i think at that point you're just going to have to start doing hyperparameter optimization the hard way